Access Spring Context from IntelliJ Platform Plugin SDK
I have a custom intellij plugin with an intellij @Service where I would like to access the Spring Context of a running application in order to access certain beans of the org.springframework.boot.actuate package.
For example, I want to 'inject' the HealthEndpoint of the Spring Actuator and display the health status of the application.
How to approach that? Also there could be multiple applications running in the IDE, so how do I access an application in general? If you have any documentation links or ideas related to this, i would highly appreciate it.
@Service(Service.Level.PROJECT)
class SpringBootActuatorService {
    // TODO: How to 'inject' the Spring Context of a running application in IntelliJ?
}


It would be helpful if you provided info what do you need the Spring Context for? Cause you can easily recreate it in your plugin code with new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MySpringConfig.class); and that will give you access to all the same beans but it won't be the same singletons (different spring context) which might be enough depending on your use case

Thank you for the answer. I've updated the question.
Update contains:
For example, I want to 'inject' the HealthEndpoint of the Spring Actuator and display the health status of the application.

but the health endpoint is a REST endpoint... so you don't need any Spring Context at all, you can just call it every second and keep getting up to date status of your app...

That is true but it also possible to inject via the Spring context directly which is the proper way. Also, I would need to receive the proper running port of the application which might be possible without the Spring Context but could still be easier with it. And when I talk about the HealthEndpoint, I talk about the HealthEndpoint class which you can inject and not the REST endpoint.

I don't think what you are asking is possible - the problem is these are 2 different JVMs - one being the intellij which runs in its own JVM and one is your Spring App which runs separately (different JVM, different process). That means there is no way for you to share spring context between the two. You have to choose a protocol to communicate between 2 different apps, it could be http or jmx or whatever

but on the off chance try asking in the slack community for plugin devs - perhaps they can help you

Alright, thanks for your answer anyway. That makes sense.
